# How to start the cloned react-native project in windows

Tags: react-native, github

I have cloned a repo and want to run it but im not able to it because im not able to find node-modules but i have copy pasted it from other project but it is still not working
after running react-native run-android it gives me following error:

> C:\Users\f2016\Documents\GitHub\almaConnectApp>react-native run-android
>   info Starting JS server...
>   info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...
>
> Configure project :app
>   Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>
> Configure project :react-native-firebase
>   react-native-firebase: using React Native prebuilt binary from C:\Users\f2016\Documents\GitHub\almaConnectApp\node_modules\react-native\android
>
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
>   Parsing json file: C:\Users\f2016\Documents\GitHub\almaConnectApp\android\app\google-services.json
>
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   C:\Users\f2016\Documents\GitHub\almaConnectApp\android\app\src\main\java\com\almaconnectapp\MainActivity.java:30: error: cannot access Client
>           BugsnagReactNative.start(this);
>                                   ^
>     class file for com.bugsnag.android.Client not found
>   Note: C:\Users\f2016\Documents\GitHub\almaConnectApp\android\app\src\main\java\com\almaconnectapp\MainApplication.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   1 error
>
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
179 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 174 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the node_module folder that you paste from a different project and run:

```
npm install
```

from within the cloned project folder. This will create the node_modules folder and download all the necessary dependencies that is listed within the package.json file inside the folder.

Comment: oh ok thanks for help

Comment: i ran react-native start after npm install but it didn't started the browser tab with qrcode

Comment: seems you are expecting react-native to run on browser, it will not

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by QR code, were you trying to run Expo? A non-expo react-native project doesn't show QR code in the packager.

Comment: oh i didn't knew that then how im gonna run my app

Comment: What platform are you running it on?

Comment: No, I mean the react-native app. What platform is the app you're trying to run on? Android or iOS? You can use react-native run-android or react-native run-ios

Comment: yes i tried running react-native run-android with an emulator but it showed me error that error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: i have updated the question please have a look

Comment: Just in case, can you try "./gradlew clean" then "react-native run-android"? Also the issue seems to come from Bugsnag. So try checking this thread here: https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-react-native/issues/235